# Does process in python have its own os.environ copy?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I'm wondering, does process in python have its own copy of `os.environ`? I.e. is it safe to set `os.environ` from the process, and is it guaranteed that it will not be overwritten from another process?

```
import os
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process


def f1(i):
    time.sleep(random.randint(0,3))

    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = str(i)
    print('i:', i)

    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 3))

    print('i:', i, "os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']", os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'])



def run_me():
    n = 3
    process_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        p = Process(target=f1, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        process_list.append(p)

    for p in process_list:
        p.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_me()
```

Example of output:

```
i: 2
i: 0
i: 0 os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] 0
i: 2 os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] 2
i: 1
i: 1 os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No process is allowed to modify the enviornment variables of another process, and every process is given its own fresh copy of enviorment variables. It will initally contain a copy of the parent process' env vars unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Look at my code I'm not directly access from one process to another, but seems each of process have it's own copy of `os.environ`.

Comment: Yes they do have their own copy. Every system process is allocated with its own set of enviornment variables that cannot be modifed by another process directly, You could set up your own custom protocol through signals or some other mechanism to modify the env vars, but the OS won't natively support that.