# Python environ variables strange behaviour when doing multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, environment-variables

I was struggling with some strange behaviour in Python 3.9 when using multiprocessing and environment variables.

I have created the following example that reproduces the issue:

```
import multiprocessing.pool
import os
import copy
import time

multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
WORKERS = 2


def method(index: int):
    print(f'* index: {index}; position: 1; env var value: {os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]} *')
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = str(index)
    print(f'* index: {index}; position: 2; env var value: {os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]} *')
    time.sleep(3)  # some task
    print(f'* index: {index}; position: 3; env var value: {os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]} *')


pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(processes=WORKERS)
pool.map(lambda index: method(index), list(range(WORKERS)))
```

The idea is to have a pool of two threads with a distinct value for the *CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES* environment variable.

The expected output would be something like the following:

```
* index: 0; position: 1; env var value: 0 *
* index: 0; position: 2; env var value: 0 *
* index: 1; position: 1; env var value: 0 *
* index: 1; position: 2; env var value: 1 *
* index: 1; position: 3; env var value: 1 *
* index: 0; position: 3; env var value: 0 *
```

The thread 0 has always value 0 for the env variable, whereas the thread 1 changes to value 1 after the 1st position.

However the resulting output is the following:

```
* index: 0; position: 1; env var value: 0 *
* index: 0; position: 2; env var value: 0 *
* index: 1; position: 1; env var value: 0 *
* index: 1; position: 2; env var value: 1 *
* index: 1; position: 3; env var value: 1 *
* index: 0; position: 3; env var value: 1 *
```

In this case, the thread 0 changes its value to 1 in the 3rd position, after the time sleep.

Why is this happening? Is this something expected with environment variables? Maybe os.environ has some shared nature? I have tried to include the line *os.environ = copy.deepcopy(os.environ.copy())* at the beginning of the function *method*, but it did not change the output. Neither including the following lines at the beginning worked:

```
os.environ = {}
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

Is there a way to make this not happening?

Comment: Threads share environment variables.

Comment: @user2357112 also processes in the multiprocessing package?

Comment: they should have different environments according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561116/does-process-in-python-have-its-own-os-environ-copy) at least, but no sure at all

Comment: Those are processes. You're using threads. `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` is a thread pool, not a process pool.

Comment: true, using multiprocessing.pool.Pool solved the issue, many thanks!:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a thread specific environment variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348556/how-to-set-a-thread-specific-environment-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), the issue was using a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead of a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. Threads share the environment, whereas processes do not. Aside from this, threads do not surpass the GIL lock of Python, not doing a proper parallelism.